# How do I save the localization in flutter

Tags: flutter, localization

I am a beginner in flutter and making an app and I implemented localization but when I exit and re enter the app it just goes back to default language.
How do I save the selected language to show when I restart the app?
This is the language changing page where list of languages will be located.

```
class LanguageSelector extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0.wp),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.back();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  'English',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0.sp),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  var locale = Locale('en', 'US');
                  Get.updateLocale(locale);
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  'Croatian',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0.sp),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  var locale = Locale('hr', 'HR');
                  Get.updateLocale(locale);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is in the main.dart file.

```
void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  await Get.putAsync(() => StorageService().init());
  runApp(const MyApp());
  }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      translations: LocalString(),
      locale: Locale('en', 'US'),
      title: 'Todo List',
      theme: Themes().lightTheme,
      darkTheme: Themes().darkTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeService().getThemeMode(),
      home: const HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialBinding: HomeBinding(),
      builder: EasyLoading.init(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences, https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences, to save the selected locale. Then load it again when you're re-launch the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to save the required data in [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). So each time you load the app we can retrieve the data stored in the mobile and use it to decide the initial state of the app.

Example code of use:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final String? language = prefs.getString('lang');
if(language == null){
    prefs.setString('lang', 'eng');
    language = 'eng';
}
```

Comment: so where should i write this exactly?

Comment: Just put this inside a function and call it in the initstate of the widget you are implementing. If the terms I used are unclear, plz update the question with the complete code of the main.dart and the other dart file

Comment: I will post the complete code but i think i understand. Thank you